# Handling messages using SOAP without creating a .xml File

Tags: java, xml, soap

I´m using Netbeans and I want to be able to create a message handler. The process to do that is:
- Create a Message Handler, from Web Service Category;
- Configure handlers, where it is generate the x_handler.xml;
- Automatically generate an annotation @handlerchain to web service;

I want with an annotation to do this without creating this file.xml. There is any possiblity to achieve that?